# Autostart works only in VNC, but not on physical screen

Tags: raspbian, vnc, screen

I have connected a screen to Raspberry Pi 4 b+ and from a Windows 10 PC I have a VNC session to the Raspberry Pi.

On the Raspberry Pi, I have added an autostart "script" and it works well... or it works only in my VNC connection window, when I look at my physical screen, it shows the Raspbian dashboard and not the http page as in my VNC session.

Can someone guide me, so I get the http page showed on my physical screen.
I have tried to restart the Raspberry Pi, but the autostart is only showed in the VNC connection, and not the physical screen.

My autostart is in `.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`

```
@lxpanel --profile LXDE-pi
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE-pi
@xset s off
@xset -dpms
@xset s noblank
@chromium-browser --kiosk --disable-session-crashed-bubble --disable-infobars https://www.google.com
```

Comment: And what happens if you disconnect the VNC session?

Comment: the physical screen just show the desktop.
I have also tried to add this:
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --kiosk --ignore-certificate-errors --disable-restore-session-state https://www.google.com
But it works in VNC when i re-connect the Pi in VNC but it's not showing it on the physical screen.

Comment: I have also tried from this folder
/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart